# Contemplate - meaning and usage

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Dictionary lists out the following meanings and usages of the word "contemplate"

> Verb 1. If you contemplate an action, you think about whether to do it
> or not.
>  Verb 2: If you contemplate an idea or subject, you think about
> it carefully for a long time.
>  Verb 3: If you contemplate something or
> someone, you look at them for a long time.
> He contemplated his hands,
> still frowning.
> contemplation UNCOUNTABLE NOUN
> He was lost in the contemplation of the landscape for a while.

I came across in a script, where the writer uses the word contemplate to convey the meaning "with thoughts about someone"

> She deeply contemplated her dying brother. (this brother is not before
> her. He is far away in a different city. She leaves immediately to see
> him after this)

Is it right to use this word in this particular context? From what I understand from the dictionary, when you contemplate someone, you actually look at them for a long time.

Comment: While examples of 'contemplated her brother' {-"brother's"} _do_ occur on the internet, they are few. A sentient being is rare as the referent of a direct object for 'contemplate'. Better avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *contemplated* is not used correctly in the following sentence:

> She deeply contemplated her dying brother.

If her brother had died, she could *contemplate* her brother's death. That would mean she thought deeply about what his death meant.

Although wordy, the sentence could also read

> She deeply contemplated the fact that her brother was dying.

Personally, I steer clear of "the fact that" habit, so a better version of the sentence could go

> She deeply contemplated the inevitability of her brother's death.

Or,

> She deeply contemplated her brother's dying.

In other words, she thought deeply about the process of dying that her brother was experiencing and the effect it was having on her and him.

In short, a person cannot deeply contemplate a person. On the other hand, a person *can* contemplate an aspect of a person, or something a person has done or said. That's about as technical, grammatically, as I can get.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. In that case, when someone says something like, "I contemplate visiting France" what do they actually mean? Are they thinking of visiting France or are they thinking whether to go to France (verb 1 meaning) ?

Comment: @Ammu: To contemplate taking a trip, a person could either be anticipating a trip they've already made arrangements for, or a trip they are thinking about taking but have yet to make arrangements or reservations for.